# Print as csv format in R

Tags: r, csv

I get a print output as following

```
[1] "Tue Mar 22 05:22:51 GMT 2016"

Estimate :
Net: 3719.262622298
Today: 773.5113933745
ON: 335.155067924
Actual: 234.1075543743
Below this tab seperated csv starts
A B C D
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
P Q R S
9 8 7 3
```

I have a javascript that supports only csv format files. My intent is to forcefully write it in csv format, filling commas with blanks or NA. Is there a way a good way to do it in R.

Comment: Show how you get this data.. and then `write.csv` part of it

Comment: Can you tell us what is the CSV file supposed to look like?

Comment: Use `write.csv` without specifying a file?

Comment: @KotaMori the csv should look like the ABCD given from the 8th line. If we remove the top 7 lines, then its pure csv.  The last line 9873in this case gives the number of columns I need to have.

Comment: From @RVij  
Try to convert it as data frame or data table

Comment: Hmm, do you want to convert the last 5 lines of the print output into something line this?  `A,B,C,D\n1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8\nP,Q,R,S\n9,8,7,3`  Also, do you have this printed output as a character object?